# Web Page Incorporated into Facebook Fan Page

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-page

I've seen people incorporated part of their website or entire website into a Facebook Fan Page.

I need example and also the tutorial how to incorporate a web page into a Facebook Fan Page.

I already have a website built in Python and I wish to have some of the web pages to be incorporated into Facebook fan page. Anyone can help with this ?

Comment: This is a **very** broad question Mr. Cool and as such is not very suited to this site.  Please read the [Facebook Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/) to learn what is and is not possible with the Facebook platform.  When you have a more specific problem/question people will be happy to help.

Comment: I've edited my question. I knew it's doable because there are even companies started selling this solution. It's specific enough and it's related to programming.

Comment: You clearly did not understand my comment;  Placing HTML into a page is very possible but if you were to read the documentation first you would see that your question is not in place here.  You have to create a Facebook application - and before you do that you'll want to read the documentation.

Comment: No it is **NOT** specific enough and at this point it is **NOT** related to programming - rather it is related to the Facebook platform.  So... once again... please read the documentation.  Here - one more click and you'll be on your way - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean that you're seeing people use iframes of their own content on Facebook Brand Pages, which is indeed a pretty common thing recently.

The documentation you're looking for is facebook's **[Page Tab Tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/)**, which walks you through how to set these up. Technically, you're building an Application on Facebook, you're just only showing it in a Page Tab, rather than on a [Canvas Page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/#canvas).

The more general documentation about **[Apps on Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/)** will almost certainly prove very useful, but make sure you remember that you only care about the Page Tab stuff, not the Canvas Page stuff.

Whilst Facebook's documentation has historically been pretty poor, they've invested a fair amount of effort into improving things recently, so you should find it relatively straightforward. Most of the code samples are in PHP, but they do still have a **[Facebook Python SDK](https://github.com/facebook/python-sdk)**. They are withdrawing support for this  SDK on 1 April 2012, so you may want to take your own copy of it pretty quickly, or look at the alternative SDKs that are probably springing up. I'm afraid on that point, I can't be of much help (I'm a C# developer, not a Python guy), but I'm sure if you ask more-specific questions on here you should get some useful answers.

It's worth bearing in mind too that Facebook have their own view onto StackOverflow at http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/, which their developers and developer-advocates *do* monitor, so don't be afraid to ask further questions if you get stuck.

Comment: Cool @Owen Blacker ! Thanks for the answer. I've actually already built the Facebook Application. What I didn't understand earlier was the setting for Page Tab. I guess having self learning a lot of things, we tend to overlook information even we have come across that.

Thanks again. Appreciate that. :)

Comment: And I didn't know about the http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/ thought I saw it real quick in some of the searches. But, good to confirm it here again. :)

Comment: Indeed. No problem. If you already have an Application set up, then it's pretty easy to get it into a Page Tab — the main things you need to watch for are that the maximum width of the iframe is fixed and that you may need to call [setAutoGrow](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow/) to make sure all of your content is visible.

Comment: Yup. Thanks for the reminder. I'm quite aware of the width limitation. :)

Comment: Yeah, that's something that's bitten us in the arse before now  :o)